# ActiveRecord::Relation getting all column_names not only of the specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find out all the column names for a ActiveRecord::Relation.

Ex. (pseudocode

blah = Blah.select('blah.*, hah.*, nah.*').where(..).joins("left outer join Hah").joins("left outer join Nah")

I'm trying to call blah.column_names but I want it to return all the columns that this relation responds to including Hah and Nah,instead of just Blah's

Or something like blah.respond_to?('column_name')

Key part is I want to do this with no rows found as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Relation` doesn't respond to columns, but you're presumably asking about the columns that the *elements* of the `Relation` respond to.

`blah.first.attributes` will return all the column methods that `blah.first` will respond to, including those for virtual columns and columns from joined tables.  Similarly, `blah.first.respond_to?` will let you check whether it will respond to a particular column method.

Comment: I'd want it to be possible without any rows returned as well.

Comment: Do you mean in the event that the `Relation` contains no elements or without accessing the DB further once you have the `Relation`?

Comment: Given the Relationc contains no elements.

Comment: @pk1m Only thing I could find that's close is the `select_values` method, but that just returns the string argument passed to `select`, albeit including all the columns you were asking about.

Comment: Thats close, I've been able to get it by doing blah.klass.connection.execute(blah.to_sql).fields.  But this requires an extra db call.  Not sure if I should parse or live with an extra db call